# PC audio output to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, audio, adc, analog

I want to connect PC audio output (mini jack) to ADC on microcontroller. Do I need to amplify the signal? I only need to distinguish low signal from high signal...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an audio signal using ATMega328?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5315/how-to-read-an-audio-signal-using-atmega328)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You will have a better chance of getting good answers if you provide more information. Describe the ADC. Clarify what you mean by "low signal" and "high signal". Have you taken any measurements of the signal?

Comment: Fix (not delete) that question before it become your nightmare :) I mean nigthmare like question ban caused by downvoted questions.

Answer (score 2):

> **Do I need to amplify the signal?**

It might be wise to measure the output signal.

PC's can have at least three types of analog audio output (plus things like USB speaker outputs):

- line-out (consumer "line-level" signals to e.g. powered monitors)
- earphone/headphone output.
- speaker output for unpowered speakers.

Some of these may need amplifications, some may need attenuation.

Comment: I mean earphone/headphone output. But is there simple way to change signal to simple 0 or 1 (but I want to keep circuit as simple as possible, so I would prefer to do that on uC)?

Comment: @mrpyo, that's a different question. You might want to click "edit" on this Q or click "Ask Question" to start a new Q. I imagine you could rectify and smooth the audio signal and use the result to switch a transistor or op-amp on, giving an input to a microcontroller GPIO pin.